# php order of execution

Tags: php, performance, short-circuiting

Say, you have a condition like this;

`if ($condition_1 && $condition_2)`

and you have the option of writing it as

`if ($condition_2 && $condition_1)`

Now, if condition_1 takes 1 ms to figure it out whether it is true or false and condition_2 on the other hand takes a lot longer, say 1000ms!, which way would you write the above condition as? the slower one on the right or on the left?

I assume that when one of the conditions is found to be FALSE, PHP would not bother to check whether the other condition is TRUE. If it did, that would be the biggest surprise of the century!

Comment: with functions running at 1000ms in an if statement, your biggest problem isn't which one is running first

Comment: This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and PHP does it. Try it and see.

Comment: @andreas! that's hypotethic question, I could have phrased the question 1ms vs 2ms, and that time, I'm sure somebody would have suggested, why bother. :)

Comment: BTW, this is why a statement like `mysql_query() or die();` works. `die()` will only run if `mysql_query()` returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C` and `C++` break on first `FALSE` in `AND` condition. This is also the case with `PHP`. So, I would suggest putting the shorter one first. This example clearly demonstrates the case:

```
function short(){
    return false;
}

function long(){
    sleep(5);// sleep for 5 secondsd
    return true;
}

if ( short() && long() ){
    echo "condition passed";
}else{
    echo "condition failed";
}
```

This will almost immediately print "condition failed" without waiting for 5 seconds....

Answer (score 9):

Conditionals are evaluated left to right. Put the shortest condition in the leftmost position. You're correct, if the leftmost condition in that if statement evals to false, the next condition isn't checked at all.